# Override functions: pressBegan and pressEnded doesn't work

Tags: swift5, xcode11

I have UITextField with fixed number of characters. I want to see in realtime how many characters I can add. I decided to use override function pressBegan or pressEnded, it doesn't matter. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, debugger just doesn't reach this breakpoint.

[image: override func]

Function is implemented in ViewController class.

And I also have this warning when start typing something:

```
[general] Connection to daemon was invalidated
```

I'll be really grateful for some advice.